# InfoPath form URL for Promoted Links "location" too long

Tags: infopath

I created an InfoPath form and it's working fine. I would like to place the URL to the form into a promoted links image tile. However, the URL is too long. I have also already trimmed the URL and it's still too long. How do I get it short enough to add so that upon clicking on the image, it opens the form directly in the browser?

Comment: What did you put in URL field? That field is required.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a small work around for this, that seems to work! I simply added the URL to the "description" box since I knew it would allow for more text (longer URL). This seems to be working. The only caveat is the URL is a faint color. So, if I can figure out how to change color to white, I'm golden!